# Jenkins: Getting build parameter description in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I want to get the description of build parameters of a Jenkins build using groovy.
I want to include this description in an email using by [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) groovy templates.

Is there some way I can achieve this?

[image: Parameter descriptions pic]

Comment: Do the – three – downvoters mind to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Parameterized System Groovy script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+System+Groovy+script):

```
...

// get parameters
def parameters = build?.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
parameters.each {
   println "parameter ${it.name}:"
   println it.dump()
   println "-" * 80
}

...
```

Note: Since [`Actionable.getActions()`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html#getActions%28%29) is **deprecated** [`allActions`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html#getAllActions%28%29) should be used instead of `actions`.

Add:

```
   println "${it.description}"
```

and there you are.

Comment: _much appreciation_ could be done with an upvote.  Please take a tour of StackOverflow